# IPhone Aggregate iTunes reporting tool

Tags: iphone, aggregate, itunes, report

Is there a tool that will aggregate all the rerpots that Apple provides on sales of apps? Apple's reporting tool is very poor and hard to use without manually pulling data into Excel each period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out AppViz by IdeasSwarm: http://www.ideaswarm.com/products/appviz/. Have been using it for the last 6 months. Also nice: the AppSales project at GitHub: http://github.com/omz/AppSales-Mobile.

Comment: AppViz is out of business, they abandoned all of their users.